# How to disable the vertical header tracking line in Win32 ListView Control

Tags: windows, listview, winapi

I am customizing Win32 ListView control and I want to remove the vertical line that is automatically drawn when I resize the headers. I am talking about the line drawn in the row area not in the header. The vertical tracking line can be restricted by handling the **HDN_TRACK** notification and changing the cxy value in notification data but there seems to be no way to restrict or remove the vertical tracking line in the row area. Anyone has any ideas on how to remove/hide/restrict that line?

[image]

The above screenshot was taken while I am tracking the header

Comment: I would be surprised to see any provision to turn a good UI into a bad UI. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Do you want to do your own drawing or just remove the line with no replacement?

Comment: I am trying to make my listview work the same as Windows Explorer listview. There is no tracking line in the row area and the minimum header size is restricted to the header label. The problem I am trying to solve is that when I restrict the header size through HDN_TRACK the vertical line in header stops moving but the line in row area continues to move and that looks ugly. So I need to either hide the line in row area or make it move just like header one.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the line just makes it harder for the user to use the control!

The easy method is probably to enable [visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx)/comctl32 v6, it seems to use live resizing instead but that might depend on the chosen theme/style.

I was able to come up with a ugly hack for the classic control:

```
HWND hLV = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_HSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL|LVS_REPORT, ...);
SendMessage(hLV, CCM_SETVERSION, 5, 0); // <--- Important

...

case WM_NOTIFY:
{
HWND hLV = ...;
NMHDR&nmh = *(NMHDR*) lparam;
switch(nmh.code)
{
case HDN_BEGINTRACKA:case HDN_BEGINTRACKW:
  LockWindowUpdate(hLV); // Block all drawing in the listview
  return false;
case HDN_ENDTRACKA:case HDN_ENDTRACKW:
  LockWindowUpdate(NULL);
  return false;
}
```

This might [depend on the HDS_FULLDRAG header style](https://thomasfreudenberg.com/archive/2004/03/14/hdn-track-and-hds-fulldrag/) and you probably don't want to do this when visual styles are enabled.

Comment: LockWindowUpdate, yuck.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yep, but it is designed to lock a single window during drag operations and WM_SETREDRAW did not want to play ball.

Comment: I did not use the CCM_SETVERSION statement but LockWindowUpdate works by hiding the line. The only problem is that it even hides the vertical tracking line for the header so now no tracking line displays.

Comment: Yes it will disable drawing in the entire listview area, there is no way around that. Other options include grabbing a screenshot of the listview and display that in your own custom window that sits on top of the listview OR subclass the listview and handle the header notifications yourself.

Comment: The listview is already subclassed and I am using comctl32 v6